# Deploying BDC Model Problem

Tags: 2013, bdc-model, visual-studio-2012

I created empty Sharepoint 2013 Project and added BDC Model into Project. It is a farm solution.

There is 2 Feature. In both of them I put BDC into **Items in the Feature** in **Feature.feature** My Feature.Template.xml files:(there is no property)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>
```

It gives this error when I deployed.

> ------ Deploy started: Project: SharePointProject1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Active Deployment Configuration: Default
>   Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not
>   specified.   Recycle IIS Application Pool:   Recycling IIS application
>   pool 'SharePoint - 80'...   Retract Solution:   Retracting solution
>   'sharepointproject1.wsp'...   Deleting solution
>   'sharepointproject1.wsp'...   Add Solution:   Adding solution
>   'SharePointProject1.wsp'...   Deploying solution
>   'SharePointProject1.wsp'... Error occurred in deployment step 'Add
>   Solution': A feature with ID 15/3700b1a8-e0be-45c6-9930-2888c8be2ad2
>   has already been installed in this farm.  Use the force attribute to
>   explicitly re-install the feature.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> Error occured in deployment step 'Add Solution': A feature Id.....
>   already been installed in this farm. Use the force attribute to
>   explicitly re-install the feature.

Why can't I deploy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably changed the name of the feature or a property of the feature.

Use the force attribute to explicitly re-install the feature.